# Rewrite Rule change URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I need all board urls changed from this:

```
http://dream-portal.net/board_65.0/
```

to this:

```
http://dream-portal.net/board_65/
```

Basically, I need to get rid of the .0 at the end of the URL, just before the last / character.

How can I do this via .htaccess?

Currently using this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You want to show in the browser's address bar this: `http://dream-portal.net/board_65/` instead of this: `http://dream-portal.net/board_65.0/` while still mapping silently to this resource: `http://dream-portal.net/index.php?q=board_65 `. ¿Is that right? ¿Is `board_65.0` a fixed string or it can change dynamically?

Comment: Well, I believe it can be changed dynamically... not sure.  Really don't care, I just need it so that when users click on board links they are taken to `{MY_DOMAIN}/board_{NUMBER}/` instead of `{MY_DOMAIN}/board_{NUMBER}.0/`

Comment: The correct URL I need is `{MY_DOMAIN}/index.php?board={NUMBER}` which, if used, will change it automatically to what I want, which is `{MY_DOMAIN}/board_{NUMBER}/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(board_[0-9]+)\.0/$ $1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ohhh wait, I need to fix .0 to whatever .{NUMBER} it is also... arggg...  How to do that?

Comment: I think you mean `RewriteRule ^(board_[0-9]+)\.[0-9]+/$ $1 [L,R=302]`